# sql basic queries

Tags: sql

Im new to sql and playing around with some example databases I have found.
I have a table called student as follows

```
id    name    expenditure      item
 1     dan      45              social
 1     dan      60              books
 2     sarah    32              food
 3     matt     64              food
 3     matt     71              social
```

I was trying to find students who spent money on both food and social but spent more money on social than food.

I tried:

```
Select name
from student
where  item = 'social' and item = 'food'
```

Comment: Think about it: how can **one** column have the value `'social'` *and* '`food'` **at the same time**?

Answer (score 7):

No individual line of data has `item = 'social'` AND `item = 'food'`.  As the `WHERE` clause applies to one row of data at a time, you can't do that.

What you need to do is group all the records together by student, and then check some characteristics of the data in that group.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  student
GROUP BY
  id,
  name
HAVING
      SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'social' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'food'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

That gives all students who have *some* records for `'social'` and *some* records for `'food'`.

Then, you can add the following to get only those who spent more on `'social'` than on `'food'`.

```
AND SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'social' THEN expenditure ELSE 0 END)
    >
    SUM(CASE WHEN item = 'food'   THEN expenditure ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 3):

`where  item = 'social' and item = 'food'`  Doesn't work because a single row can never be both. When comparing two rows from the same table the easiest way is to do a self join

```
SELECT
   s1.Name
FROM student s1
     INNER JOIN student s2
      ON s1.id = s2.id
WHERE
    s1.item = 'social' and s2.item = 'food' 
    and 
    s1.expenditure  > s2.expenditure
```

Notes:

1. If you have multiple rows for the same type of expenditures you'll want to use [Dem's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457293/119477) of summing the different types and then comparing
2. If you want to include people who haven't spent any money on food you'll have to use a LEFT JOIN. You'll also to move the test for 'food' into the ON clause otherwise it will act like an inner join.

   ```
    LEFT JOIN student s2
     ON s1.id = s2.id
       and s2.item = 'food'
   ```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8186/1)